# Не запускается Android Debug Bribge (adb) из Android-SDK

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-sdk

Запустил свой эмулятор Android-SDK (запустился нормально) на своей Ubuntu 14.04 (32-бит), попытался установить из консоли в созданный девайс приложение:

```
adb install program.apk
```

получил ошибку:

```
adb: 1: adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Вызов из терминала без параметров:

```
$ ./adb
bash: ./adb: cannot execute binary file: Ошибка формата выполняемого файла
```

вывод команды:

```
$ file ./adb
./adb: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,
BuildID[sha1]=90addc5e3980f6efab749c9032cc8d7ad60dfb94, not stripped
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: для работы с sdk нужна 64-битная система.

Comment: То есть, как это? Буквально неделю назад все прекрасно работало (в .profile установлен ключ export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true), а сейчас вдруг стало работать только на 64-битах? Чето странно как-то...

Comment: вероятно, мы с вами под «sdk» понимаем разные вещи. [A 64-bit environment is required for Gingerbread (2.3.x) and newer versions, including the master branch. You can compile older versions on 32-bit systems.](https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html)

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `file ./adb`.

Comment: Добавил вывод команды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ./adb: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64

эта программа скомпилирована для исполнения в 64-битной операционной системе.

вы же написали, что используете 32-битную.

---

уточнить битность своей операционной системы можно командой:

```
$ getconf LONG_BIT
```

в 32-битной она выведет `32`, в 64-битной — `64`.

---

**обновление**

программа *adb* присутствует в пакете [android-tools-adb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/android-tools-adb/filelist). если вы установите этот пакет нормальным образом, с помощью пакетного менеджера (*apt** и т.п.), то установится сборка для нужной вам битности и архитектуры.

Comment: Да это понятно. Не понятно только почему именно adb не работает с 32-битами и почему на той же рабочей станции до переустановки системы - ранее стоял  Linux Mint 32-бит - он уже отказывается работать? Впрочем, сам эмулятор работает себе вполне отлично и не жалуется на 32-бита :)

Comment: я обновил ответ.